# How to Find Cause of -- Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, commonjs

I'm using gulp with browserify, to bundle an app. While the build is functional, I continually receive the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s}'
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing the error or how to debug it? The only time the error does NOT appear is when there are zero `require` statements in the main js file. For reference below are the gulp and main.js files:

*gulpfile*

```
var gulp, browserify, stringify, sass, concat, uglify, source, buffer;

gulp = require('gulp');
browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
stringify = require('stringify');
sass = require('gulp-sass');
concat = require('gulp-concat');
uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

function handleError(err) {
    console.log(err.toString());
}

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js', { read: false })
               .pipe(browserify({
                   transform: [stringify({
                       extensions: ['.html'],
                       minify: true
                   })]
               }))
               .on('error', handleError)
               .pipe(concat('main.js'))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin/js'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
               .pipe(sass())
               .on('error', handleError)
               .pipe(concat('main.css'))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin/css'));
});

gulp.task('index', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'sass', 'index']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['browserify']);
  gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./src/index.html', ['index']);
  gulp.watch('./src/html/**/*.html', ['browserify']);
});
```

*main.js*

```
'use strict';

var $ = require('jquery'),
    ko = require('knockout'),
    greet = require('./components/greet');

window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.userName = ko.observable('');
}

ko.components.register('greet', greet);
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in the browser console?  What JS files are being loaded directly from the HTML?  Do you still get the error when the minification is turned off?

Comment: Yes, the error appears in the browser console. Only one JS file, main.js, is loaded from the HTML. Currently no minification is taking place, only concatenation.

Comment: You should boil this down to a minimal example. Get rid of everything from `gulpfile` and `main.js` that isn't necessary to trigger the error. Post those and the bundle code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you concat multiple browserified files. To solve that you have simply to concat before browserify

```
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js', { read: false })
               .pipe(concat('main.js'))
               .pipe(browserify({
                   transform: [stringify({
                       extensions: ['.html'],
                       minify: true
                   })]
               }))
               .on('error', handleError)
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin/js'));
});
```